# Is it possible to install CDH on a RHEL7 server where Hadoop and few other components are installed seperatly

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, rhel7

I have an RHEL7 server in which i am trying to create a common datalake platform for POC and learning purpose. I have setup **Hadoop,Hive,Zookeeper,Kafka,Spark,Sqoop** separately.

Installing these components separately turns out to be a tricky affair and is taking lot of effort even though this is for an internal purpose and not production specific.

I am now trying to install CDH package in this Server now.
Is it possible to do so? Will it overlap with the current installations?
How can this be achieved.

*Note: Reason why we went with separate installation is due to unavailability of internet in the server at that point of time*.

*Reason why going for CDH now is due to availability of internet for few days after some approvals plus CDH saves lot of time and effort and includes the
components required to setup a datalake.*

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: This is very broad. The answer is probably *yes you can given enough time, patience, panedol (headache pain relief) and willpower to succeed*.

Comment: Download the RPMs (but don't install) and see where the contents will be placed to see if you will have file conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is feasible to setup CDH without disturbing existing configs with docker. Checkout the below link for setup guide. I have tested this and it works fine even if I have individual tools setup.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html